# Как вывести определенные свойства из массива объектов. JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть массив объектов, допустим:

`let obj = [{
  name: 'Tim',
  age: 20,
  email: '123@.com'
  },
  {
  name: 'Tom',
  age: 25,
  email: '456@.com'
  }]`

Мне нужно вывести определенные свойства которые заданы в массиве:

`let arr = ['name', 'age']`

Как пытался делать я:

`obj.forEach(el => {
  arr.forEach(elarr => console.log(el.elarr))
})`

Answer (score 1):

Сам спроси, сам отвечу: `console.log(el[elarr])`